# Estimate convergence rate for recurrences $a_{k} \le \frac{k}{k+2} a_{k-1}$ and $b_{k} \le \frac{k+\alpha}{k+2} b_{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

Suppose a positive sequence satisfies the recurrence $$a_k \le \frac{k}{k+2} a_{k-1}$$ for $k \ge 2$. If we do the expansion, then
\begin{align*}
a_k \le \frac{k}{k+2} a_{k-1} \le \dots \le \frac{6}{(k+2)(k+1)} a_1 \in \mathcal O(\frac{1}{k^2}).
\end{align*}
Now suppose $$b_k \le \left( \frac{k}{k+2} + \frac{\alpha}{k+2} \right) b_{k-1}$$ where $\alpha$ is some positive number. I would expect $b_k$ reduces at a slower rate. Let us take $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$. Mathematica gives a solution
\begin{align*}
\frac{ \Gamma(1+2k)} {\Gamma(4+2k)}= \frac{1}{4(k+1)(k+2)(3+2k)}.
\end{align*}
This seems to be a better asymptotes.
 Where does it go wrong? $b_k$ should not reduce faster than $a_k$.

Comment: How do you get that asymptotic order for $b_n$?

Comment: More generally, if $$c_k\leqslant\left(1+\frac{\gamma}k+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\right)c_{k-1}$$ one can be sure that $$c_k\leqslant Ck^\gamma$$ For the sequence $(a_k)$, $$\gamma=-2$$ For the sequence $(b_k)$, $$\gamma=\alpha-2$$ hence if $\alpha=\frac12$ then $$\gamma=-\frac32$$ (No appeal to the Gamma function is necessary to establish the fact above.)

Comment: @Did: I could not see how you get second inequality $c_k \le Ck^{\gamma}$. Could you elaborate a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: For every $C$ and $\gamma$, there exists $D$ and $k_0\geqslant2$ such that,, for every $k\geqslant k_0$, $$1+\frac{\gamma}k+\frac{C}{k^2}\leqslant\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)^\gamma e^{D/k^2}$$ And now, *concatenate*...

Comment: @Did: I see. Thanks. If you are still available, would you mind taking a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621833/estimate-rate-of-convergence-for-recurrence-a-k1-le-1-frac-alpha-k.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the first part:
\begin{align}
a_k &\leq \frac{k}{k+2}a_{k-1}\\
&\leq \frac{2}{4\!\!\!\times}\frac{3}{5\!\!\!\times}\frac{4\!\!\!\times}{6\!\!\!\times}\frac{5\!\!\!\times}{7\!\!\!\times} \dotsb \frac{k-2}{k}\frac{k-1}{k+1} \frac{k}{k+2}a_1\\
&= \frac{6}{(k+1)(k+2)}a_1 \in O\left(\tfrac{1}{k^2}\right)
\end{align}

But I don't agree with your Mathematica result.
\begin{align}
b_k &\leq \left(\frac{k}{k+2} + \frac{a}{k+2}\right) b_{k-1}
= \left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-2} \frac{k+a-i}{k+2-i}\right) b_1
= \dfrac{\prod_{i=2}^{k} (i+a)}{\prod_{i=4}^{k+2}i} b_1\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(k+a+1)\,/\,\Gamma(a+2)}{\Gamma(k+3)\,/\,\Gamma(4)} b_1
= \frac{6}{\Gamma(a+2)}\frac{\Gamma(k+a+3)}{(k+a+2)(k+a+1)\Gamma(k+3)} b_1
\end{align}

A useful asymptotic approximation, for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^{\alpha}}=1$$
then
\begin{align}
b_k
&\leq \frac{6}{\Gamma(a+2)}\frac{(k+3)^a}{(k+a+2)(k+a+1)}\frac{\Gamma(k+a+3)}{(k+3)^a\Gamma(k+3)}b_1\\
&\sim \frac{6 b_1}{\Gamma(a+2)} \frac{(k+3)^a}{(k+a+1)(k+a+2)}
\in O\left(\tfrac{1}{k^{2-a}}\right)
\end{align}

As long as I haven't messed up somewhere this should give $O\left(\tfrac{1}{n^{1.5}}\right)$ for $a=\tfrac12$.